# Magentoo add slashes to file_name

Tags: php, magento

I try extend an core class.
But catch error:
Warning: include(
\\\\\\\\\\\\MyModule\Ajaxsearch\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Product\Collection
\\\\\\\\\\.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:...

Why magento add slashes to addres? May be config error?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `magic_quotes_gpc` by commenting the flag in the `.htaccess` file.